# I want to calculate actual time taken by docker to start , stop a container

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on my ubuntu 14.04 machine and able to perform operation like start stop commit on container . but i am not able to find any mechanism to calculate actual time taken by docker to perform all operation.
please help me to provide solution to calculate actual time in docker

Answer (score 1):

Try simply using:

```
time {command}
```

**Example:**

```
> time docker run busybox echo

real    0m0.344s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Comment: @prateek-arora Please let us all know if this answer worked for you, thanks!